# Unable to attach to created process with Visual Studio 2005

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2005, debugging

I'm having problems attaching to a process spawned from one of my own processes. When I attempt to attach to the process using Visual Studio 2005 (Debug -> Attach to process) I receive the error message: "Unable to attach to the process. The system cannot find the file specified."

In my program, I spawned the process that I later want to attach to using the command

```
BOOL res = CreateProcess(exe, cmdLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE, 0, NULL,
                         workingDir, &startupInfo, &procInfo);
```

If I manually start the second process from the command prompt, I can attach to it without any problems. I am also able to attach to it using WinDbg, just not Visual Studio 2005. There is no difference whether I've started the first process from within VS (thus running as an administrator) or if I've started it from the command prompt as a regular user. I am running Visual Studio as an administrator under Vista 64 bit and the executables are all 64-bit.

Has anyone seen this before or have any ideas of what I might be doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Update:
I've also tried to set the security attributes for the new process and thread using the following code:

```
DWORD dwRes, dwDisposition;
PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL, pAdminSID = NULL;
PACL pACL = NULL;
PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[2];
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld =
    SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthNT = SECURITY_NT_AUTHORITY;
SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
LONG lRes;
HKEY hkSub = NULL;

// Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
if(!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1, SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pEveryoneSID))
{...}

// Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
// The ACE will allow Everyone read access to the key.
ZeroMemory(&ea, 2 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[0].grfInheritance= SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName  = (LPTSTR) pEveryoneSID;

// Create a SID for the BUILTIN\Administrators group.
if(! AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthNT, 2, SECURITY_BUILTIN_DOMAIN_RID,
    DOMAIN_ALIAS_RID_ADMINS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &pAdminSID)) 
{...}

// Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
// The ACE will allow the Administrators group full access to
// the key.
ea[1].grfAccessPermissions = GENERIC_ALL;
ea[1].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
ea[1].grfInheritance= SUB_CONTAINERS_AND_OBJECTS_INHERIT;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
ea[1].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_GROUP;
ea[1].Trustee.ptstrName  = (LPTSTR) pAdminSID;

// Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(2, ea, NULL, &pACL);
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) 
{...}

// Initialize a security descriptor.  
pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH); 
if (NULL == pSD) 
{...} 

if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD, SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION)) 
{...} 

// Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, TRUE, pACL, FALSE))
{...} 

// Initialize a security attributes structure.
sa.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    CreateProcess(exe, cmdLine, &sa, &sa, ...
```

with no luck.

**Update:** I am also able to attach to the process using Visual Studio 2008 (still compiled using VS2005), which solves my immediate needs. Since this is under Vista x64, could there be some form of "Vista magic" at play here, where VS2005 does not play nice with Vista? Why this is the case only for processes that I've built and started from my code I cannot really understand...

Comment: Are you able to attach to other processes?

Comment: Yes I am, I can attach to other processes (like notepad.exe) that I have started in the same way. Just not my exe, regardless of whether I am building in release or debug mode or 32/64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I finally found out what caused this problem. I'll post it here in case anyone else encounters this (from the scarcity of answers I guess it ain't that common, but hey...).

The problem was that the path used to launch the executable contained a path element consisting of a single dot, like this:

```
c:\dir1\.\dir2\program.exe
```

which apparently made VS2005 go look for an executable at

```
c:\dir1\dir1\dir2\program.exe
```

that of course does not exist... Thank you Mark for [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)! Removing the . made attaching to the process work as expected again.

Answer (score 4):

I had same error for Win7. I solved it.
I was trying to remote debug by attaching to a running service. Then i finally found that I need to run msvcmon as administrator.

Comment: +1: though it's not an answer to the specific situation in the OP's question, it is likely to be helpful for others with a similar problem (and welcome to SO)

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to define correctly so named SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
you give it as this NULLs  CreateProcess(exe, cmdLine, NULL, NULL,
as in such case they defines by system
and probably defines with VS permissions
and VS does not allow to debug its own processes obviously ;)

Comment: I updated the initial post about the attempt I did with setting the security attributes, which unfortunately did not seem to help... You are correct that default security attributes would be used, however there is no difference between whether I've started the first process from within VS or from a command prompt, so I don't think this is a problem with attaching to a process started by VS per se.